# 'var' data is not readable in other call back function

Tags: javascript, node.js

---

I can save and read 'var' variables in one callback function, but in other callbacks, I cannot read them. They become 'NaN'. How can I make these 'var' become readable everywhere?

---

I have a web server and it is connected by two Android devices. One is the sender, the other is a receiver.

Each device connects to the server and gets their id. Also, server saves their id to:

```
var senderId;
var receiverId;
```

These `Id` variables are saved and it can read in its callback function, 
but when I use another callback function, the server cannot read these Id variables. they are only 'NaN', also unable to parsing.

Could you give some advice about make variables save data consistently?

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
const express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var senderId = 0;
var receiverId = 0;
// ...

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected.');

    //so here is setting the ID variables
    //receiving a username and if he is a receiver, save he's id to receiverId

    socket.on('join', function (userNickname) {
        if (userNickname == 'receiver') {
            // ...
            receiverId = socket.id; //save he's receiverId
        }
    };

    if (userNickname == 'sender') {
        // Similiar as reciever
        senderId = socket.id; //save he's senderId
    }

    // I can read senderId, receiverId well here
    console.log('receiver socket id :' + receiverId);
    console.log('sender socket id :' + senderId);
    // These Id looks like G0s5Vy-E5f01-JxUAAAD ...
});

// But when I use another call back function, these ID variables are not able to read!

socket.on('send_ytsc', function () {
    console.log("receiver id :" + receiverId);
    console.log("sender id: " + senderId);
    // These Id returns 'NaN', even though I use String(receiverId)
});
```

Comment: `NaN` is a value, somewhere in your code you're assigning `NaN` to the variables.

Comment: You might want to use `console.log("receiver id :" , receiverId);` no the addition of string and number

Comment: I agree with Teemu. Also, `G0s5Vy-E5f01-JxUAAAD` is indeed not a number, it is a string. There is no need to wrap it in `String(()`

Comment: thank you for answering. I did operate `if( (receiverId*1)!=0 )` for some checkings 
 but it made these value to NaN. It was my poor mistake.